# Do I need to release object using delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a task to do without ARC. Previously I didn't use it (started studying ios development recently). I have a class that represents http request, it conforms to NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate protocol. And also I have following code:

```
-(void)executeWithRelativeUrl:(NSString *)relativeUrl andSuccessBlock: (void(^) (NSData*))successBlock {
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:relativeUrl relativeToURL:self.baseUrl];
    [self setSuccessBlock:successBlock];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
    [downloadTask resume];

    [request release];
    [url release];
}
```

that creates url session and starts download task. I'm dealing with task results in following method:

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.successBlock(data);
    });

}
```

Now the question is: do I need to release session, download task and location url in the end of the last method? Or it will be done for me? I'm asking this because I created it in the first method (except for url), and as I understand the one who is responsible for releasing the object is also me. Thanks!

Comment: It is better if you have the downloadTask as a property or in an array or some reference to it so you can cancel it if you need it too etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Golden Rule](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_the_golden_rules_of_memory_management) is very simple. Did you say `alloc` or `copy` or `retain`? No? Then you don't need to say `release` (and you must not do so).

(You need to release the `url` and the `request` for that reason, and you are doing so. So memory management is now complete.)

Comment: I said it in the first method, allocating session and download task. Or objects in the second method are not the same?

Comment: You didn't show any code that "allocates" the session and download task. So what are you even talking about?

Comment: Ah... I got them not with explicit 'init'. I understand now. Thanks a lot for answer!